# I need a PHP mySQL Login script that directs user to specific URL based on username and password

Tags: php, login-script

Can anyone show me or point me in a direction that shows to assign a specific URL to a user based on their Username and Password?

Erik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you put that URL in the database associated with that user in question. If the query for the user and password are TRUE, then redirect to that URL associated to that user.

Here's an example, let says that you have 1 user in the database called "users" with the fields:

- id (Id with autoincrement and set as Primary key)
- user (Username)
- pass (Password)
- url (The url for the redirection)

And the login.php form is like

```
    <?php
    //Database connection
    $sql = mysql_connect("localhost","dbUsername","dbPassword");
    mysql_select_db("dbName", $sql);

    if ($_POST['submitLogin'){
     //Login query
     $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user LIKE '".$_POST['user']."' AND pass LIKE '".$_POST['pass']."'");
     $r = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);
     if (mysql_num_rows($q) >= 1){
       //If the user / password are found -> redirect
       header('Location:'.$r['url']);
     }else{
       //else return the login error
       echo "Login failed";
    }
    ?>


    <form action="" method="post">
     User : <input type="text" name="user" /><br>
     Password : <input type="password" name="pass"/><br>
     <input type="submit" name="submitLogin" value="Login"/>
    </form>
```

I think this should do the trick :D

Comment: Sounds great.  I'm new to php and I'm really suffering...  Need to find an example.

Comment: Note, the above code is not really production ready.
 
- stuff in SQL query needs sanitising - e.g. mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user LIKE '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']) . "' AND .....)  
- There is a lack of error checking (not checking if DB is there, or if queries have succeeded).  
- You should also exit(0) after you do a header() redirect, else the stuff beneath it will be executed/shown.

Answer (score -1):

The way you'd send the query and parse the result would depend on whether you're using mysqli, PDO, or something else to access your database. Lets say you're using mysqli.

Assuming the database connection is referenced in $dbc and you've got your username and password in $user and $pass, and have validated them, and sanitized them for use in a query, you could do something like:

```
$query = "SELECT url FROM table_name WHERE user = $user AND pass = $pass";
$result = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $query);

if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    header ('Location: ' . $row['url']);
    exit;
}
else{

    // Handle invalid username/password

}
```

Very basic, and you'd use SHA1 or whatever encryption you're using to store passwords in the query.

Comment: If you use the snippet given by Warface please do make sure that, if nothing else, at the very least you at least sanitize the username and password submitted, or you'll land up with a very insecure system. This means, when you're setting $q, replace `$_POST['user']` with `mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST['user'])`, and the same for `$_POST['pass']`