# Login form redirect from specific url

Tags: php, redirect

I need to create a form that inserting username and password present in a mysql db redirect the user to a specific link always present in the database.
I have already created the database containing ID, Email, Password, url.
Can someone explain to me the easiest way to make sure that by inserting a user's username and password, he redirects it to the assigned link?

Thank you

I have this:

LOGIN PAGE:

$conn = require_once 'config.php';

$mysqli = new mysqli($conn['mysql_host'],$config['mysql_user'],$config['mysql_password'],$config['mysql_db']
);

```
if ($_POST['login'){
 //Login query
 $q = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE email LIKE '".$_POST['email']."' AND password LIKE '".$_POST['password']."'");
 $r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q);
 if (mysqli_num_rows($q) >= 1){
   //If the user / password are found -> redirect
   header('Location:'.$r['url']);
 }else{
   //else return the login error
   echo "Login failed";
}
```

Comment: just google properly you will get perfect answer or refer w3school

Comment: I try to search in google, but non found results for this.. Only result is this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805008/i-need-a-php-mysql-login-script-that-directs-user-to-specific-url-based-on-usern ... but not work

Comment: can you please confirm what i understood. You want to redirect your user to specific url which is associate with that user name and password if both are proper and correct.

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: help me please.

Answer (score 3):

You can redirect by sending the Location header:

```
header("Location: https://www.google.com");
```

Comment: I need redirect after user login with username and password, associated at username and password there is a link..